# Configure server for gitlab

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ruby, gitlab

I have a server where VestaCP installed (apache2 is back-end, nginx is front-end). Also, I successfully installed ruby, gitlab shell and gitlab. When I type

```
 sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
```

Everything shows OK.

And there is one issue - configure server for it. I tried to copy [this](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-apache2.4.conf) to new template, but apache2 won't start after it.

Now I have a clean web server provided by vestacp and gitlab installed, so it's not need to "repair" apache2 server.

Comment: Solved it! Edited /home/%user%/conf/web/apache2.conf file!

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new WEB site in VestaCP named `source.example.com` (change it to yours, of course)
2. Open `/home/%user%/conf/web/apache2.conf` file. Delete all things related to `source.example.com`. Paste [this](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-apache2.4.conf) and edit it for your needs.
3. Restart apache

Done.